# TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression in FastAPI Middleware

Tags: python, fastapi, middleware, starlette

```
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
from starlette.routing import Mount
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

class CustomHeaderMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
         customer =stripe.Customer.retrieve(request.session.get("user"))
         r= stripe.Subscription.list(customer=customer.id,limit=3)
         if r.data[0].status =="incomplete":
            raise HTTPException(401)
        #  response= RedirectResponse(url='/gradio')
         
         response = await call_next(request)
        
         return response  
 
io = gr.Interface(lambda x: "Hello, " + x + "!", "textbox", "textbox")

middleware = [
    Middleware(CustomHeaderMiddleware)
]

routes = [
    Mount('/gradio', app=io, middleware=middleware),
]
app = FastAPI(routes=routes)
```

File "C:\Users\Shivam 112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 69, in coro
await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)

TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Are you using [gradio](https://gradio.app/quickstart/)?

Comment: The traceback is incomplete and your question exhibits no debugging effort. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `routes` argument in the `FastAPI` constructor does not accept plain `Starlette` routes. There is probably a way to work around that, but there is an even easier solution. Looking into `gradio` a bit, it turns out that their web app **is** a `FastAPI` application, meaning we can [add the middleware in the normal way](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#adding-asgi-middlewares), and then [mount the gradio app as a sub application](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/?h=sub#mounting-a-fastapi-application):

```py
import gradio
import gradio.routes
import stripe
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, status
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware


class CustomHeaderMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
        customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(request.session.get("user"))
        r= stripe.Subscription.list(customer=customer.id,limit=3)
        if r.data[0].status =="incomplete":
            return Response(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        response = await call_next(request)
        return response

io = gradio.Interface(lambda x: "Hello, " + x + "!", "textbox", "textbox")

# Create gradio FastAPI application
gradio_app = gradio.routes.App.create_app(io)
gradio_app.add_middleware(CustomHeaderMiddleware)

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/gradio", gradio_app)
```

Also, raising an `HTTPException` only works in a FastAPI route, not in a middleware, which is why I'm returning a plain response instead.